# One of my classes will not output anything

Tags: java, class, tostring

so I need some advice, I have been working on some code for quite a while and I can never seem to find out why my code is screwing up terribly. It seems as if one of the toString lines in my Product class is not working properly. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class lab24ArrayList
{

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();

        Product hat = new Product ("Hat", 10);
        Product scarf = new Product ("Scarf", 8);
        Product legos = new Product ("Legos", 19);
        Product dvd = new Product ("DVD", 12);

        System.out.println("Removing DVD: "+cart.remove(dvd));

        cart.add(hat);
        cart.add(scarf);

        cart.remove(scarf);


        System.out.println("Removing Scarf: " +cart.remove(scarf));

        cart.add(legos);
        cart.add(dvd);
        cart.add(legos);

        System.out.println(cart);


    }
}

class ShoppingCart
{

    ArrayList <Product> cart;

    public ShoppingCart()
    {
        cart = new ArrayList<Product>();    
    }

    public int  size()
    {
        int k = cart.size();
        return k;
    }

    public void add(Product p)
    {                                            
        cart.add(p);                

    }
    public Product remove(Product p)
    {
        if(cart.contains(p))
        {
            cart.remove(p);
            return p;
        } 
            else
                return null;
    }   

}

class Product
{
    private String name;
    private double price;

    public Product(String _name, double _price)
    {
        name = _name;
        price = _price;
    }

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public double getPrice() {return price;}
    public String toString() {return name + ": $"+price;}

}
```

When I put it in the compiler, all I get is this:

```
Removing DVD: null
Removing Scarf: null
ShoppingCart@c2f0bd7
```

When I need to get this:

```
Removing DVD: null
Removing Scarf: Scarf: $8
Items: 6
Total: $60.00

Hat: $10
Legos: $19
DVD: $12
Legos: $19
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your `toString()` method... `Scarf` is removed twice, the second time returning `null` as no items are left. `ShoppingCart` does not override `toString()` and thus prints whatever Object.toString() returns.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `toString()` method on your ShoppingCart, that's why you get `ShoppingCart@c2f0bd7`. Override `toString()` in the `ShoppingCart`class to build a string from the items within it.

You're also removing the Scarf twice, once here `cart.remove(scarf)` then also in `System.out.println("Removing Scarf: " +cart.remove(scarf))`.

To clarify how to print out the cart, you'll want to create a toString method in ShoppingCart similar to what you've done in Product:

```
public static String toString() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for(Product product : cart) {
        stringBuilder.append(product);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

That creates a StringBuilder, loops through each product in the cart and appends it to the StringBuilder. You then return that string.

Comment: So how would one exactly go about building this string? I don't see exactly what you put in, and whenever I try to call the Product class I screw up.

Comment: I've added an explanation as to how you could print out the cart by creating a toString method in ShoppingCart.